# Where can I go surfing near Arrábida, Portugal?

Tags: portugal, beaches, water-sports, surfing

Could you suggest me where can I go surfing near [Arrábida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arr%C3%A1bida_Natural_Park), as beginner/intermediate surfer?

I’ve been in places such as Ericeira a bit more in the north, or Caparica. I would prefer to have to do a short ride to get there. Are these the only possibilities?

Comment: how far do you consider nearby to be?

Comment: @nsn Well, if I'm correct, Caparica which is the example in my question takes 45mins/1 hour to reach. Under that time